# In PowerShell, what is technically the "help" command?

Tags: powershell

I'm new to PowerShell and noticed that executing `help` and `Get-Help` are two distinct things, the former behaving like `Get-Help | more`.

My first thought was that maybe `help` is an alias to `Get-Help` but obviously it can't be an alias if it behaves differently and indeed, it isn't.

So what is `help`? Is it some built-in function? A cmdlet with non-standard naming convention? (BTW, similar question could be asked about `more` and possibly others.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do

```
Get-command help
```

You'll see it's in fact a function

Then by doing

```
get-content function:\help
```

You'll see ilt's basicly a call to Get-Help | more

Comment: Just one interesting thing I've noticed, why does `help help` return help on `Get-Help`, not the `help` function?

Comment: I guess it's because of this in the function definition :<#
.FORWARDHELPTARGETNAME Get-Help
.FORWARDHELPCATEGORY Cmdlet
#>

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a post on the difference between the two long time ago:

http://scriptolog.blogspot.com/2007/11/help-vs-get-help.html